# Tradingview Invite only scripts

Tags: tradingview-api, indicator

Greeting,,

Is there any a way to copy invite only scripts from tradingview?

I want to copy a script and add some modifications

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to ask the owner of the script to let you see the code.

The pinescript manual state :
**Can I access the source code of ‘Invite-Only’ or ‘closed source’ scripts?**
No. Closed source scripts are called that because the source will permanently be closed to everyone but the creator. Invite-Only scripts are also closed source, but they differ because they have an additional restriction: only users on the invite list can add the script to their charts.
ref : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/faq/Programming.html?highlight=invitation%20only#can-i-access-the-source-code-of-invite-only-or-closed-source-scripts

Answer (score 0):

You aren't able to copy the invite-only script without permission from the publisher. Also, note that once you get permission you may still not have access to the code depending on if the script was published as protected or open